# How to Namespace in C# with alias

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

what is the meaning of: In the MainWindow.xaml, bring the Contoso.Data namespace into scope? and also Bring System.Windows.Forms namespace into scope with the alias WinForms?? How to do this?

Comment: check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

Comment: so for MainWindow.xaml, bring the Contoso.Data namespace into scope what I will do is namespace Contoso.Data { }. Just like this?

Answer (score 4):

To bring a namespace into scope use the `using` keyword like so..

`using System.Text;`

To create an alias of a namespace..

`using WinForms = System.Windows.Forms;`

You can learn more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: Thanks Travis another thing is that when I type using Contoso.Data; an error shows unknown type or namespace

Comment: Then this means you don't have a reference to the library. On the menu bar go to, Project -> Add Reference. Then locate your reference and add it.